# Xamarin.Forms development with old Macbook Pro

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a new Surface Laptop 3 for Windows development.  I'm just starting to learn Xamarin.Forms and I'm using Visual Studio 2019.  The device emulators work fine as does debugging on a physical Android.  I'd like to debug on an iOS device.  However, I only own a Late 2011 MBP (16GB RAM, SSD).  I am limited to High Sierra and XCode 10.1.  Is this Macbook good enough for me to at least debug and just learn Xamarin.Forms using iOS devices?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements#macos-requirements

Comment: Thanks Jason.  It looks like I'm able to just get by, according to that.

Comment: Hi , if comment solved your problem ,you can update it as an answer when you have time :-)

Answer (score 0):

*If* you want to release your app some time soon, you'll be required to use the iOS 13 SDK ([source](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09102019a)). To use the iOS 13 SDK you'll need Xcode 11+, unfortunately

> Xcode 11 requires a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later. ([source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes#overview))

And Mojave is not intended to run on devices older than 2012 ([see here for example](https://www.macworld.com/article/3278597/ios-12-watchos-5-tvos-12-and-macos-mojave-device-support.html#toc-4)). Anyway, this does not necessarily mean that you can't use your old MBP at all. Even though Mojave is not intended to run on devices that old, people have been able to run it anyway. Have a look at [dosdude1's Mojave patcher](http://dosdude1.com/mojave/). I have been able to successfully install Mojave on my (early 2011) MBP and it works without any reason for complaint. **However**, since the OS is not intended to run on our MBP YMMV.

And **please note** (shamelessly [copied from this answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/379274/302581))

- This is probably a violation of Apples ToS
- If you want to release your application in the App Store you might still run into troubles (unlikely, albeit, still conceivable)
- You'll have to trust dosdude1, the patches are not open source, as far as I can tell
- The machine is not guaranteed to work as it did before